# Как получить часть строки?

Tags: c

Цель: в `ip`, получить часть строки после "А". Однако при компиляции ругается:

> ```
> etip.c:60:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer
> from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>                   strcat(ip,str[i]);
> ```

```
char str[50];      
int i;
int flag;
char ip[50];

strcpy(str,"sufeiuA215.10.30.40");
strcpy(ip,"");
flag=0;
for (i=0;i < strlen(str);i++){
    if (str[i] == 'A') flag=1;
    if (flag == 1) strcat(ip,str[i]);            
};       
printf ("IP: %s",ip);
```

Comment: Где же тут с++?

Answer (score 1):

`str[i]` — это не строка. Вы не можете сконкатенировать строку с символом.

Возможно, вы хотите так:

```
char *p = strchr(str, 'A');
if (p != NULL)
    strcat(ip, p + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

В gcc/g++ можно одной строчкой

```
strcpy(ip, ({char *t = strchr(str, 'A'); t ? ++t : "";}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[50];
    unsigned int i;
    int flag;
    char ip[50];

    strcpy(str,"sufeiuA215.10.30.40");
    strcpy(ip,"");
    flag=0;
        for (i=0;i < strlen(str);i++){
          if (str[i] == 'A') flag=1;
              if (flag==1){
                 strcat(ip,&str[i + 1]);
                 break;
              }
          }
    printf ("IP: %s\n",ip);
}
```

Comment: Это решение предполагает, что ip будет в конце строки.

Comment: Хм.. Оказывается, это написано в условии. Но зачем тогда `strcat` вместо `strcpy`?

Comment: `if (str[i] == 'A') flag=1; if (flag==1) {` - ну ооочень полезный флаг.

Comment: Топикстартер просил работоспособный код. Он его получил.

Answer (score 0):

<s>http://codepad.org/pNdH0SGR</s>
http://codepad.org/JHc84ZJp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
  {
  char str[50] = "sufeiuA215.10.30.40";
  char ip[50], *s;
  unsigned q, i;

  if(!(s=strchr(str,'A')))
    *ip=0;
  else
    for(++s,q=0,i=0; s[q]; ++q)
      if(s[q]=='.' && ++i==3)
        {
        while(s[++q]>='0' && s[q]<='9');
        strncpy(ip, s, q), ip[q]=0;
        break;
        }

  puts(ip);
  return 0;
  }
```

А использовать strcat неэффективно.

---

Если ip всегда находится в конце строки (т. е. от первого символа `A` и до конца строки), то можно сделать проще:

http://codepad.org/f41xdmPL

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
  {
  char str[50] = "sufeiuA215.10.30.40";
  char ip[50], *s;

  if(!(s=strchr(str,'A')))
    *ip=0;
  else
    strcpy(ip, s+1);

  puts(ip);
  return 0;
  }
```

Кстати, в этом случае, если потом ни одну из строк менять не планируется, можно просто использовать указатель s без всякого копирования.